# Problems with my LVM partition, showing wrong size and brings I/O errors on vgscan?

Tags: linux, partitioning, lvm, linux-kvm

I have a volume group with 3 logical volumes.
1. lv is used for a virtual webserver, 2. is a old backup of lv 1 and the 3. is a storage volume.

Now my first lv throws i/o errors and is no longer accessible.

```
lvscan
  /dev/DATA/WEBSERVER1: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 52428734464 i/o error
```

I set the first one to inactive and than I checked the output of the lvscan:

```
  1. inactive Snapshot '/dev/DATA/WEBSERVER1' [19,53 GiB] inherit
  2. ACTIVE            '/dev/DATA/WEBSERVER1-bak_final_cloud_resspace' [48,83 GiB] inherit
```

Yesterday 1 was 48,83 GiB (like its backup 2), now it only shows 19,53 GiB. I use both LVs in a KVM for virtualisation so they are not containing 48,83 GiB but reserve it and claim it if needed.

Something must be wrong with the LVMs LV – can I somehow recover it to get the original size and content back?